# Developing Linux C++ program on a specific device

Tags: architecture, linux-kernel, fpga

I've built Linux on a FPGA (Zedboard) with customized hardware using a open source hdl, and now I want to add applicationg to use this hardware.

My problem is that I have to build the hardware using 2013 version Vivado, but I want to use a 2018 Xilins SDK to develop my application, which would not accept the old version of hardware specification.

So is it possible to use C++ without hardware specification? Would it cause any trouble later when I try to use drivers for my customized hardware?

Or to be more general, when I have my Linux running, can I just use my drivers in the to operate my hardware without concerning the hardware importing issue?

Comment: Classically programs running under a full operating system have little awareness of hardware specifics, but rather interact only with operating system- and driver- provided abstractions that behave in a somewhat standard way.  Of course there are expections...   Since your question lacks specifics it is not really answerable.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisStratton , it's much clear now, and I think I just need to get the driver right whenever the devce changes, and programs will be fine.